Are contour operators over filters the most general form of ''filter morphism" w.r.t. intersection?
Let two sets $X$ and $Y$, and a function ${\cal F}:X\to {\rm Filters}(Y)$, that is: for every $x\in X$, ${\cal F}_x$ is a filter on $Y$. Then, given any filter ${\cal G}\in{\rm Filters}(X)$, its contour along ${\cal F}$ is defined as
$$ {\cal F}({\cal G}):= \bigcup_{A\in\cal G} \bigcap_{x\in A}{\cal F}_x$$
and it is still a filter on $Y$ (the proof is mechanical). Furthermore it is easy to show that this ``contour operator'' is a morphism w.r.t. filter intersections, in the following sense:
Prop. 1. For every collection of filters $({\cal G}_i)_{i\in\cal I}$ in ${\rm Filters}(X)$, one has
$$ {\cal F}(\bigcap_{i\in{\cal I}}{\cal G}_i)=\bigcap_{i\in{\cal I}}{\cal F}({\cal G}_i)$$
The proof is mechanical (it uses the fact that the elements of $\bigcap_i{\cal G}_i$ are the sets of the form $A=\bigcup_i A_i$ with every $A_i\in{\cal G}_i$).
Now, my question is about the reverse implication: If an application ${\cal F}:{\rm Filters}(X)\to{\rm Filters}(Y)$ is such that, for every collection of filters $({\cal G}_i)_{i\in\cal I}$ in ${\rm Filters}(X)$, one has
$$ {\cal F}(\bigcap_{i\in{\cal I}}{\cal G}_i)=\bigcap_{i\in{\cal I}}{\cal F}({\cal G}_i)$$
does ${\cal F}(\cal G)$ necessarily correspond to a contour operator?

My advances on the question : if we let ${\cal F}_x:={\cal F}(\{\{x\}\}^\uparrow)$, then the commutation of ${\cal F}$ with filter intersections easily implies that, for ever ${\cal G}\in{\rm Filters}(Y)$:
$$\bigcup_{A\in\cal G} \bigcap_{x\in A}{\cal F}_x \subset {\cal F}({\cal G})$$
However, I fail to prove the reverse inclusion. My intuition is that the reverse inclusion does not hold true in general, and so, ${\cal F}$ does not correspond to a contour operator  in general.
But so I far, I have not figured how to build a concrete counter-example.

Oooof, the counter-example wasn't that hard to find after all.
On $X$, let ${\cal U}$ be any nonprincipal ultrafilter (i.e., ${\cal U}$ is not of the form $\{\{x\}\}^\uparrow$ for some $x\in X$).
On $Y$, let ${\cal T_0}:=\{Y\}$ be the trivial filter, and ${\cal H}$ any other filter different from ${\cal T_0}$.
We then introduce the application ${\cal F}:{\rm Filters}(X)\to{\rm Filters}(Y)$ defined by
$$ {\cal F}({\cal G})=\begin{cases} {\cal H} &\textrm{if ${\cal G}={\cal U}$} \\
{\cal T_0} &\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
On the one hand, this application ${\cal F}$ is a "filter morphism" as required, i.e., it verifies
$$ {\cal F}(\bigcap_j{\cal G}_j)=\bigcap_j{\cal F}({\cal G}_j)$$
Indeed: if $\forall j,{\cal G}_j={\cal U}$, then ${\cal F}(\bigcap_j{\cal G}_j)={\cal F}({\cal U})={\cal H}=\bigcap_j{\cal F}({\cal G}_j)$; and in all other cases, $\bigcap_j{\cal G}_j\neq{\cal U}$ (because ${\cal U}$ is an ultrafilter) so ${\cal F}(\bigcap_j{\cal G}_j)={\cal T_0}={\cal T_0}\cap{\cal H}=\bigcap_j{\cal F}({\cal G}_j)$.
On the other hand, ${\cal F}$ is not a contour operator. Indeed, if we let, for all $x\in X$, ${\cal F}_x={\cal F}(\{\{x\}\}^\uparrow)={\cal T_0}$, then we have
$$ \bigcup_{A\in{\cal U}}\bigcap_{x\in A} {\cal F_x} = \bigcup_{A\in{\cal U}}\bigcap_{x\in A} {\cal T_0} = {\cal T_0}$$
whereas ${\cal F}({\cal U})={\cal H}$. So ${\cal F}$ differs from its "associated" contour operator.
In summary: contour operators are "filter morphisms" w.r.t. filter intersections, but not every "filter morphism" w.r.t. filter intersections is a contour operator.
(Which raises a new question: is there a simple S.N.C. on a "filter morphism" ${\cal F}$ for it to correspond to a contour operator?)
